# When magento widgets are run for the first time do they alter the database?

Tags: database, magento, widget

I've been following this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1 to create a Magento widget as part of an extension I'm working on.

Whilst the widget was created successfully and worked as I wanted it, I changed the code and started getting the following error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php on line 502
```

When I changed the code back, the error was still present. However when I copied **all** my module to a fresh Magento install then the error wouldn't appear.

Although my widget does not explicitly use the database does anyone know if the act of installing and uninstalling a Magento widget makes changes to the core databases tables and if it does, which tables are altered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The core_resource table contains a list of all modules, so adding a new module will cause a new row to be created.

If you have anything in your module's sql folder, that code will be run depending on your module's version.

Without knowing exactly what code was run and changed, it's hard to know what your specific problem is.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Comment: I didn't think that **all** modules showed up in the core_resorces table, only those that actually has some install code. I've taken a look and can only see one of my modules in the core_resources table, and this is the only one that has a sql instal file. Do you know if there are any other files which get modified if a widget is installed. Thanks for trying, I know my original question wasn't the most useful.

Comment: I believe that all modules do show in there.  Inside the admin, goto system > configuration > advanced and expand "disable modules output". Do you see all your modules listed there?

Comment: Yup, I can see all my modules there, but isn't that list just populated from the app/etc/modules XML files and not the database? I can see my module name in the list, but when I do a wildcard search with phpmyadmin across all columns of all tables the module name is not present.

Answer (score 0):

So if you followed that tutorial you linked to I do not think it changed any database settings.

You can tell if a module will add tables or modify table columns by the following method.

Assume the module is called Foo_Bar and it is installed in the "community" code pool (as opposed to core or local).

Navigate to app/code/community/Foo/Bar. You will at minimum usually see etc and Block directories there.
If you see a sql directory then this module makes db changes. You also need to understand a module is versioned and may initially make a certain table and then modify it.

By way of example you can go to any core module and look for the same. For example I am running Enterprise 1.12 and went to:
app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/sql/sendfriend_setup

I see:
mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.3-0.7.4.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.2-0.7.3.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.1-0.7.2.php
mysql4-install-0.7.0.php
install-1.6.0.0.php

Note the upgrade x-y nomenclature. That is what core_resource keeps track of.

If you are wondering where your new module's settings are saved, that is actually in core_config_data. try this:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%foo%';
```

Assuming you have some setting in the admin you named "foo".

Now back to your problem. That is a common php error. You are running a foreach on something which can not be iterated. The code right before that is probably not returning an array or collection or whatever.

Ideally you should always wrap the foreach with a statement that checks that the item you are iterating over is not empty.

You can also turn off displaying errors or suppress that error using the @ statement which is a bad practice...

Comment: Thanks, I understand how Magento Extensions alter the database via the files in the sql folder. My problem is that the extension I've been working on ** does not** explicitly alter the database, but I was wondering if there were some implicit changes happening to the database when my widget extension was run.

Comment: The problem is that my extension code was, I made some changes and it started throwing the error , I changed the code back but the error remained, I copied all my extension code into a fresh install of Magento where it would run without the, but the identical code was still throwing the same error on the original install. Even deleting all my extension code from the original install and then putting it back still gave the error. To me this smacks of changes happening somewhere in the database.